# Basic Authorization in Grails

Tags: grails

I am rewriting an old Grails (1.3) application to a more recent Grails 2.5.0 application. In the old application the developer put something like this for basic authorization:

`clientRequest.getMetaData().putSingle("Authorization", "Basic" + encodebase64(user:pass))`

In my Grails 2.5.0 application I am using Apache's html library.
I tried doing:

`request.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String((userid + ":" + password).getBytes()))`

But I'm still getting a 401 (Unauthorized) message back.

Comment: I think he is taking 'user:pass' and your are taking 'userid:pass' may be you can check that